# Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp' : none of the solution already there worked

Tags: xcode, firebase

so im having this error again:

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'FirebaseApp'.
```

**I already tryed multiple thing:**

-udpating pod in the console

-writing manualy and using autoFill for command instead of copy-past from Firebase website.

-"import Firebase" or the module 1 by 1 didnt work either

-recreated the project from scratch already

-restarted Xcode

-cleaning with shift+alt+cmd+k  then rebuild

**Version i have :**
Xcode 10

IOS 9

Using Firebase (5.14.0)

Using FirebaseAnalytics (5.4.0)

Using FirebaseAuth (5.1.0)

link for detail :
http://img110.xooimage.com/views/b/7/d/capture-d-e-cran-...01.00.27-55787b9.png/

Comment: You are accessing your project with the .xcworkspsace file instead of the .xcodeproj file, right?

Comment: yes i am using the good one , white one.

Comment: can you post your podfile? Something is wrong as if your podfile is set up correctly, running cocoapods.app and using that file should install everything you need in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Pod to install Firebase, right? For some reason it's not being installed or found by Xcode. I just followed the steps on the docs and got it working on Xcode 10.1. Create a new project, close Xcode, go to folder using terminal:

```
 pod init
```

Add this line to the Podfile that will be created:

```
 pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

On the terminal:

```
pod install
```

Open Xcode, clean build. Make sure to open the .xcworkspace file, not the .xcodeproj.

[image]

Comment: Yep i did that already i'm afraid, but i found out that having: "import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth" make it work  but that créate another problem with firebase , it doesnt handle the new user account anymore.